.NET MAUI - RefreshView Content is not visible inside a Grid with Row Auto
After migrating to MAUI I have a problem with showing RefreshView Content when the RefreshView is wrapped around Grid and RowDefinition is Auto.
<Grid RowDefiniot="Auto">
<RefreshView IsEnabled=true, IsVisible=true>
<Label Text=" This is refresh label..."/>
</RefreshView
</Grid>

If I change RowDefinition with *, the content is shown but I want to auto size the content. My current version for maui is 8.0.92.

I can reproduce your problem and this is because the RefreshView's Height is 0 when it is wrapped around Grid and RowDefinition is Auto. You can report this on the github repo.
